# Term store Vs Categories

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, term-store, categories, enterprise-wiki

On this link   http://www.jasperoosterveld.com/2011/09/creating-knowledge-centre-with_07.html, they define a managed term store hierarchy , then users can add categories  when adding new wiki articles if the keyword is not in the term store hierarchy . so does this mean that we can use  Term store and categories  to refer to each other, and what are the differences between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category is a predefined Term Set that is made in the term store management.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but let say users are allow to insert new categories on the fly when adding new wikis, where will these categories be in the term store hierarchy?

Comment: if your term set is open users can add terms and be displayed in the term store hierarchy

Comment: thanks again for your reply, but on which level and under which parent term set the new category will displayed??, as users will just type the new category name without specifying the parent term set when adding a new category on the fly.

Comment: whenever users add a new term i advice they use the panel. If the click the square next to the text box of the categories they are able to point out where the new term should be added